# When does Accept Rate display?

Tags: discussion, support

Does anyone know what the criteria is for a user's accept rate to display under their names for each question they ask? I could have sworn I've seen it displayed before but I just realized I don't notice it under anyone who is asking a question anymore. Is there any reason this isn't displayed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that this has been removed in the [latest build](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654):

> Starting with the next build accept rate will no longer be shown.
>
> We're still keeping track of it on the backend for various things, but
>   the negative behavior its display encourages outweighs its benefits.